# Analyzers in ElasticSearch not working

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

I am using ElasticSearch to store the Tweets I receive from the Twitter Streaming API. Before storing them I'd like to apply an english stemmer to the Tweet content, and to do that I'm trying to use ElasticSearch analyzers with no luck.

This is the current template I am using:

```
PUT _template/twitter
{
  "template": "139*",
  "settings" : {
    "index":{
      "analysis":{
        "analyzer":{
          "english":{
            "type":"custom",
            "tokenizer":"standard",
            "filter":["lowercase", "en_stemmer", "stop_english", "asciifolding"]
          }
        },
        "filter":{
          "stop_english":{
            "type":"stop",
            "stopwords":["_english_"]
          },
          "en_stemmer" : {
            "type" : "stemmer",
            "name" : "english"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "tweet": {
      "_timestamp": {
        "enabled": true,
        "store": true,
        "index": "analyzed"
      },
      "_index": {
        "enabled": true,
        "store": true,
        "index": "analyzed"
      },
      "properties": {
        "geo": {
          "properties": {
            "coordinates": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            }
          }
        },
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "english"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I start the Streaming and the index is created, all the mappings I've defined seem to apply correctly, but the text is stored as it comes from Twitter, completely raw. The index metadata shows:

```
"settings" : {
    "index" : {
        "uuid" : "xIOkEcoySAeZORr7pJeTNg",
        "analysis" : {
            "filter" : {
                "en_stemmer" : {
                    "type" : "stemmer",
                    "name" : "english"
                 },
                 "stop_english" : {
                     "type" : "stop",
                     "stopwords" : [
                         "_english_"
                     ]
                 }
             },
             "analyzer" : {
                 "english" : {
                     "type" : "custom",
                     "filter" : [
                         "lowercase",
                         "en_stemmer",
                         "stop_english",
                         "asciifolding"
                     ],
                     "tokenizer" : "standard"
                 }
             }
         },
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "version" : {
            "created" : "1010099"
        }
    }
},
"mappings" : {
    "tweet" : {
        [...]
        "text" : {
            "analyzer" : "english",
            "type" : "string"
        },
        [...]
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? The analyzers seems to be applied correctly, but nothing is happening :/

Thank you!

PS: The search query I use to realize the analyzer is not being applied:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "_index:1397574496990"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match_all": {}
            },
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "geo.coordinates"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "geo.coordinates",
    "text"
  ],
  "size": 50000
}'
```

This should return the stemmed text as one of the fields, but the response is:

```
{
   "took": 29,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 47,
      "successful": 47,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0.97402453,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "1397574496990",
            "_type": "tweet",
            "_id": "456086643423068161",
            "_score": 0.97402453,
            "fields": {
               "geo.coordinates": [
                  -118.21122533,
                  33.79349318
               ],
               "text": [
                  "Happy turtle Tuesday ! The week is slowly crawling to Wednesday good morning everyone ☀️#turtles… http://t.co/wAVmcxnf76"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "1397574496990",
            "_type": "tweet",
            "_id": "456086701451259904",
            "_score": 0.97333175,
            "fields": {
               "geo.coordinates": [
                  -81.017636,
                  33.998741
               ],
               "text": [
                  "Tuesday is Twins Day over here, apparently (it's a far too often occurrence) #tuesdaytwinsday… http://t.co/Umhtp6SoX6"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

The text field is exactly the same that came from Twitter (I'm using the streaming API). What I expect is the text fields stemmed, as the analyzer is applied.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing is happening"? Analyzers don't affect the way data is stored. They only affect the way data is indexed. Did you try to search on the analyzed field to see if stemming work? Did you try to use [analyze](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) method to see if your analyzer is getting applied?

Comment: The analyze method with my custom analyzer works, but when I try to retreive the field "text" with a GET query the analyzer is not being applied, so there is something I am doing wrong :/

Comment: Can you add an example of the data that you are trying to search and the search query that doesn't work?

Comment: I added the search query I am using and the response I obtain. As for the data, it's the response obtained from the Twitter Streaming API, so it's quite big. The point is: The "text" field is not being stemmed, even the mapping seems fine. Thanks you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analyzers don't affect the way data is stored. So, no matter which analyzer you are using you will get the same text back from source and stored fields. Analyzer are applied when you search. So by searching for something like `text:twin` and finding records with the word `Twins`, you will know that stemmer was applied.